# Schema validation for Json array of objects using Java

Tags: java, json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am looking for JSON Schema validation in java code for an array of data.

My JSON Schema is

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "acc": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "AccId": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "accName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "accSysName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "accLName": {
              "type": "string"
            }
           },
          "required": [
            "AccId",
            "accName",
            "accSysName",
            "accLName"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "acc"
  ]
}
```

while my JSON response for 1 record is

```
{
  "acc": [
    {
      "AccId": 123,
      "accName": "test",
      "accSysName": "ABC",
      "accLName": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code from http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/ works fine in the above case but in the below case it doesnt go for the check of the second record , that is when JSON response has multiple objects.

JSON response for multiple records:

```
{
  "acc": [
    {
      "AccId": 123,
      "accName": "test",
      "accSysName": "Abc",
      "accLName": "test"
    },
    {
      "pqr": 456,
      "qwe": "test2",
      "accSysName": "ghu",
      "accLName": "test3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with additionalProperties / additionalItems: false as well, yet it didn't work for either of them which I had checked for few old posts in Stack Overflow as well but didn't get the desired result.

Is there any other way in which it can work?

Comment: Try to indent your code with 4 spaces to improve readability.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To validate your json response . Copy and paste your json response in link below 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

It will tell you that your json is valid or not

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong form of `items`. The form you want should look like this.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": { "type": "string" }
}
```

This will validate that all items are strings

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

The other form of `items` describes something like a tuple.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    { "type": "string" }
    { "type": "integer" }
  ]
}
```

This validates that the first item of the array is a string and the second item is an integer. Anything passed the second item is ignored (unless you use `additionalItems`)

```
["foo", 1]
```

So, in your schema, you've defined a tuple of one element and the rest are ignored. Switch to the first form and it will work as you expect.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "acc": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "AccId": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "accName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "accSysName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "accLName": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "AccId",
          "accName",
          "accSysName",
          "accLName"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "acc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, not sure what you meant by wrong form of items ..cause I am still getting Not Valid inspite of passing correct values and amending the schema..Could you please try explaining with my example..

Comment: I updated the answer to include the corrected schema.

Comment: let me know how can I connect to you cause I need urgent solution for this as I have been struggling from quite long for this :(

Comment: I think you have copy pasted the same schema as I now see that the response gives Valid even for the second record though it is passing incorrect key, i assume the checking is not taking place for the second record

{
  "acc": [
    {
      "AccId": 7377,
      "accName": "test0504",
      "accSysName": "AIM",
      "accLName": "test0504"
    },
 {
      "AccId": 7378,
      "cb": "test0585",
      "accountingSystemName": "AIM",
      "accountLongName": "test0504"
    },
 
  ]
}

Comment: The change I made to the schema is small, but very important. I changed `"items": [ { ... } ]` to `"items": { ... }`. The difference between these two are described in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , a last query in this post , what if my schema has datatype "string" and the Json response as "null" or any "integer" value , it gives me invalid , how do I make my schema loosely coupled so that the main focus is on the field mapping test and datatype can be universal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you only want it to only validate properties if the subject is an object, all you have to do is leave out `"type": "object"`. Anything that is not an object will pass because `properties` and `required` only apply when the subject is an object. If I misunderstood the question, you can make another question and explain with examples.

Comment: for my schema :
"AccId": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "accName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "accSysName": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "accLName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
    "name": {
              "type": "null"
            }          
          }
and my response
"acc": [
    {
      "AccId": 7377,
      "accName": "test0504",
      "accSysName": "AIM",
      "accLName": "test0504",
   "name":"bcbc"
    }
I get invalid how do I make the type generic?

Comment: Setting `"type": "null"` means the value must be `null`. You can allow it to be a string or null with `"type": ["string", "null"]`, but it's recommended to just not passe the value instead of explicitly passing `null`.

Comment: Perfect it worked :) , one last query hopefully it is 
my schema:

Comment: Perfect it worked :) , one last query hopefully it is 
my schema:
 {"AccId": {
              "type": ["integer","null"]
            },
            "accName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "accSysName": {
              "type":  ["string", "null"]
            }}
json response
{
      "AccId": 12,
      "accName": "test0504",
      "accSysName": "A",
      "accLName": "tes",
   "name":"bcbc"
    },
 {
      "AccId": 73,
      "cb": "te",
      "ab": "y",
      "accLName": "test0504",
   "name":"xyz"} }
continue in next

Comment: The schema checks the first one and second one is not checked and gives valid though the keys are different than schema

Comment: I can't tell from this excerpt of the schema. It could be a problem with `required` or `items`.

Comment: input has trailing data after first JSON Text I get this error while using "items": { ... } instead of  [ { ... } ] any syntax that needs to be put post or pre in this ? ... too many questions for you ..:)

Comment: on using  [ { ... } ]  it trails ahead with no issues or error but doesnt check the next record's keys though it is incorrect.. the schema is just the way u mentioned in your previous comment .. and your comment about using "type": ["string", "null"] worked well for me..thanks a lot for it ,.schema now checks for the null /string both contents

Comment: I am not sure If I am correct I tried using oneOf and additional properties , this worked and trailed through tooo with no errors... let me know if any options are there ..Thanks again for your help on this